# How to read the correct values from Parquet files?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I want to read the Parquet files I get from the readSteam() method from a Kafka topic. However, when I read these Parquet files, I get a dataframe that I don't want instead of real values.

```
import glob

parquet_files = glob.glob("/home/ubuntu/tmp/output" + "/*.parquet")

parquet_df = spark.read.parquet(*parquet_files)

parquet_df.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+--------------------+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
| key|               value|      topic|partition|offset|           timestamp|timestampType|
+----+--------------------+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|null|[22 7B 27 74 69 6...|electricRaw|        0|   127|2023-06-03 22:05:...|            0|
|null|[22 7B 27 74 69 6...|electricRaw|        0|   124|2023-06-03 22:04:...|            0|
|null|[22 7B 27 74 69 6...|electricRaw|        0|   125|2023-06-03 22:04:...|            0|
|null|[22 7B 27 74 69 6...|electricRaw|        0|   126|2023-06-03 22:04:...|            0|
+----+--------------------+-----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
```

If I want to extract the value's column as below, I get it encrypted.

```
df = parquet_df.select("value")
df = df.select("value").withColumnRenamed("value", "new_value")
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+
|           new_value|
+--------------------+
|[22 7B 27 74 69 6...|
|[22 7B 27 74 69 6...|
|[22 7B 27 74 69 6...|
|[22 7B 27 74 69 6...|
+--------------------+
```

My goal is to get the real data in the value column. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column value is of type byte array, you need to decode it to ASCII format, try this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
byte_array_to_ascii = udf(lambda x: bytearray(x).decode('utf-8'))
df = df.withColumn("ascii_value", byte_array_to_ascii("value"))
df.show()
```

If it didn't work, it's probably because of format of the value column, then try this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, hex, unhex, col
from pyspark.sql import functions
hex_to_ascii = udf(lambda x: bytearray.fromhex(''.join(filter(str.isalnum, x))).decode('utf-8'))
df = df.withColumn("value", functions.hex(col("value"))).withColumn("ascii_value", hex_to_ascii("value"))
df.show()
```

Comment: I got error since "udf" is not defined, can you please explain what is "udf"? I fixed the issue in a different way, btw. Thanks  anyways.

Comment: @Burak udf is an import from pyspark.sql.functions, I updated my code

Comment: Both work fine and both create an updated data frame containing the ASCII values column, which basically solves my problem. I also implemented a piece of code I found as a solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To see the full content of a column in spark just set

```
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: This code just runs longer binaries as output, not a solution, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Select the "value" column with binary values
binary_column = parquet_df.select("value")

# Convert binary values to string
binary_as_string = binary_column.select(binary_column.value.cast("string").alias("value_string"))

# Show the binary values as strings
binary_as_string.show(truncate=False)
```